# Ubuntu 16.04 on extended partition. Would formatting primary partition affect boot? (new Linux user)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

*Preface: this is more of a curiosity question, and may have been asked somewhere else, but I couldn't find a concise answer. Also note that I have basically no data on my hard drive, so a complete format and reinstall IS AN OPTION but simply not my preferred option. Linked below are some articles I have read.*

My primary question is in the title. I have installed Windows 98 bootloader on the primary partition of the C drive, which I set to be about 4 GB of FAT32. After failing to install Windows 2000 Server, I decided to pause the  Windows experiment and install Ubuntu (16.04 LTS) on the extended partition for dual boot. After some more research it seems that if I change the primary partition to be 2 GB of FAT16, that Windows 2000 Server may be able to run. This leads me to a couple of questions.

- Can I reformat the primary partition as FAT16 using a tool such as [gParted](https://gparted.org/display-doc.php%3Fname%3Dmoving-space-between-partitions) using a live CD/USB?
- Would this affect Ubuntu/GRUB's ability to load? Seems like GRUB has roots in the MBR which is not on the primary partition (?)
- Can I be sure that my computer (previously Windows 7 Starter) has MBR and not UEFI, and what are the consequences of each?
- If the above would result in boot failures, can I change/move the [active partition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition/OperatingSystemsAndPartitions) using gParted or fdisk?

Listed below is the output of `fdisk` on Ubuntu.

```
Disk /dev/sda: 232.9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x6ea14b78

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *           63   8193149   8193087  3.9G  b W95 FAT32
/dev/sda2         8194046 488396799 480202754  229G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5         8194048 486395903 478201856  228G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       486397952 488396799   1998848  976M 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

Also, if helpful, here is `sfdisk`:

```
/dev/sda: 30401 cylinders, 255 heads, 63 sectors/track
```

To clear things up:

- According to [this site](https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/legacy-bios-vs-uefi-bios):

> If you are using Linux, then you can check if your system has a `/sys/firmware/efi/` directory. If this directory exists, then your computer is booted in UEFI mode.

- I don't have that directory. I'm assuming that means I'm booting in BIOS.
- I can see files for GRUB on the extended partition, but the primary partition is set as active. How does this work? The only file I can see that might be relevant is `INF000.SWP` (on the primary partition).

---

Please don't make fun of me for messing around with old operating systems. [My PC](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02861759) was as slow as dirt with Windows 7 Starter, so this has been a fun little quarantine experiment. This question will hopefully clarify some things about booting, sectors, and GRUB for myself and others. :)

Again - this is a learning experience for me. Any advice helps.

Other articles I have read: [GRUB Bootloader](https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/grub-2.html), [Similar question about GRUB](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/305345/where-is-grub-installed-and-do-i-need-a-new-one-for-a-separate-linux-installatio)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps. Depends on where you installed GRUB's bootloader into. If it was installed into /dev/sda1, reformatting would break GRUB. If, as recommended, it was installed into /dev/sda . you can reformat /dev/sda1 with no problem.

Comment: I installed Ubuntu from a USB. As far as I can tell, GRUB appears to be on /dev/sda5 ... but is there some way to confirm that?

Comment: Seeing that you are doing this for fun, have a Ubuntu install USB/DVD handy and format sda1.  If Ubuntu does not boot, boot into USB and re install grub.  sda1 is the partition that boots the computer, most likely contains grub.  On slow computer would also try Lubuntu/Xubuntu, lighter weight versions.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I may try that or do a complete format and go with a lightweight version.